# Using std::any_of with lambda calling overloaded equality operator

Tags: c++, lambda, stl-algorithm

I have the following class:

```
Class Foo {
public:
    bool operator ==(const Foo& f);
    ...
private:
    set<pair<int,int>> points;
    ...
}
```

The overloaded equality operator returns true if two Foo objects have equal sets of points. It works as expected if I use it as such:

```
Foo a = Foo();
Foo b = Foo();
if (a == b) ...
```

My question is, why does the following fail to compile?

```
vector<Foo> foos = ...
Foo c = ...
if (any_of(foos.begin(),foos.end(),[c](const Foo& f) { return (f == c); }))
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: You should post the compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your lambda, `f` is `const`. So you can't call your `operator==` on it, because your `operator==` is not `const`. So fix that:

```
bool operator==(const Foo& f) const;
```